# How to synchronized data using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'am try to get data from someone database references, but when i'll do `onDataChange` it's synchronized method so all my logics app chrashed. I want to do first `fast_get_innfouser` method,then `get_all_user` and after all `root.addValueEventListener(`. How i must to do that?

There is code:

```
public class chatRooms extends Activity {

private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private FirebaseDatabase database;
public FirebaseAuth auth;
private ChatInfo ChatInfo = new ChatInfo();
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private FirebaseUser user;

private ArrayList<String> all_uid = new ArrayList<>();
private  User us ;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_rooms);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null) {
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        root.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                get_all_user(database.getReference());
                fast_get_innfouser(database.getReference(user.getUid()));
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                root = database.getReference(user.getUid()).child("chat");
            }
        });

    }


    root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
           /*........some code here...........*/
}

    });
}



 private void get_all_user(DatabaseReference reference) {
    all_uid = new ArrayList<>();
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
       //some code here
            }

        }  
    });
    }



private void fast_get_innfouser(DatabaseReference myRef) {

    final Integer[] temp = {1};
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  //some code here
               }
```

json:

[image: m2ZN-VWQ2QI.jpg]

Comment: do you have json example of the database..
    "friends" : { ..    }

Comment: @KgaboL , yes, updates

Comment: @KgaboL, why you need json?

Comment: wanted to check at what level you supposed to be getting reference for the user but looks like your users are at the top level, can you attach stacktrace?

Comment: @KgaboL, my qestion is how to synchronized some methods, i have an error when i do `root.addValueEventListener`, it's becouse my other method do after `root.addValueEventListene`.

Comment: Your use of Transaction is not correct and does not appear to serve any purpose. Your code does not do anything with the mutable data, and [doTransaction()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Transaction.Handler) returns null when it should return success or abort.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a great use case for [RXjava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid).

Here are some bindings for rxjava and firebase: (Note I haven't tested them - I wrote my own)

> https://gist.github.com/gsoltis/86210e3259dcc6998801
>   https://github.com/nmoskalenko/rxFirebase

Then you can use [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)/[concat](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) to take your multiple requests and then combine them and act on them at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try move   get_all_user(database.getReference()); to inside onDataChange inside method  fast_get_innfouser method

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check as reference(or just use it) one of the next libraries which use Reactive model with RxJava:

RxJava : https://github.com/nmoskalenko/RxFirebase

RxJava 2.0: https://github.com/FrangSierra/Rx2Firebase

One of them works with RxJava and the other one with the new RC of RxJava 2.0. If you are interested of it, you can see the differences between both  [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0).